# How can I stop loading unnecessary script files before page loads in Vue.js?

Tags: vue.js, performance, frontend, vuejs3, lowcode

I'm currently writing a Vue.js app inside a low-code platform. The platform contains unnecessary libraries like bootstrap. When I checked my app for performance, I noticed that because the platform contains bootstrap under the hood, bootstrap files are getting loaded alongside my project. I am looking for a solution that helps to remove unnecessary scripts files that are connected to html. I don't just want to remove them, but I really want to stop them from loading because I don't need those scripts to be running in my project

I tried to use some of the lifecycle hooks of Vue.js like `mounted`, `beforeMount`, `setup` and then I selected `script` tags that aren't necessary and I set their `src` attribute to empty string. But that didn't help me to prevent them from loading. The unnecessary scripts are really slowing my website down

Comment: No, those files are downloaded exactly once for each client.  The browser then loads them from the local cache.  What makes you think your web site is slowing down?

Comment: You can't prevent the scripts from loading from inside vue app because they have already being loaded at the time when vue app is running. It's unknown if it's a real problem. Bootstrap shouldn't significantly slow down anything, and it's cached after the first load

Answer (score 0):

Given you're trying to use `Vue` inside of another application and your `Vue` code doesn't trigger that request for the `Bootstrap` library, you can't prevent it, unfortunately.